# Fitting of multiple plots at the same time

Tags: r, loops, curve-fitting

I've plotted multiple graphs from a dataframe using a loop.
Follows an example.

```
    x   A   B   C
    0   0   0   0
    0.19    0.001131393 0.001745809 0.001668907
    0.3 0.001429213 0.00049965  0.001148412
    0.4 0.001695406 0.003537125 0.003828002
    0.52    0.008619063 0.006173816 0.005020359
    0.65    0.009701003 0.011902414 0.00692129
    0.78    0.014973553 0.014699063 0.008631738
    0.9 0.022978523 0.025137949 0.010629969
    1   0.038357458 0.035322334 0.013898219
    1.5 0.045039437 0.06393291  0.018679434
    2   0.052570609 0.073514007 0.021755901
    3   0.050651474 0.070495418 0.022576778

par(mfrow = c(1, 3)) 
loop.vector <- 2:4
x <- c(0, 0.19, 0.3, 0.4, 0.52, 0.65, 0.78, 0.9, 1, 1.5, 2, 3)
for (i in loop.vector){
   y <- df[,i]
plot(x, y,
        main = paste(colnames(df)[i]),
}
for (i in loop.vector){
   y <- df[,i]
   fithill <- nls(y~max(y)*x^n/(k^n+x^n), start=list(n=4, k=1))
   summary(fithill)
   curve(predict(fithill, newdata = data.frame(x=x)), add = TRUE)
}
```

I would like to have the fitted curves added to the correct graph. How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the curve after you plotted the figure. Why don't you do it like this:

```
for(i in 2:4){
fithill <- nls(df[,i]~max(df[,i])*x^n/(k^n+x^n), start=list(n=4, k=1))
plot(df[,1], df[,i],
        main = paste(colnames(df)[i]))
curve(predict(fithill, newdata = data.frame(x=df[,1])), add = TRUE)
}
```